# Check induction proof that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^ni\left(i+1\right)=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)}{3}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

claim: $\sum _{i\:=\:0}^n\:i\left(i+1\right)\:=\:\frac{n\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)}{3}$

base case n = 0

$\frac{0\left(0+1\right)\left(0+2\right)}{2}$ ; $0\:=\:0$

inductive hyp (n = k):

$\sum _{i=0}^k\:i\left(i+1\right)\:=\:\frac{k\left(k+1\right)\left(k+2\right)}{3}$

to show: n = k+1

$\sum 
_{i=0}^k\:i\left(i+1\right)\:=\:\frac{\left(k+1\right)\left(k+1+1\right)\left(k+1+2\right)}{3}$

$\sum _{i=0}^k\:i\left(i+1\right)\:=\:\frac{\left(k+1\right)\left(k+2\right)\left(k+3\right)}{3}$

not sure what to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case $n=k+1$:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\:i\left(i+1\right)\:=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\:i\left(i+1\right)+(k+1)(k+2)$$

Using inductive hyp we get:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\:i\left(i+1\right)\:=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}+(k+1)(k+2)=$$

$$(k+1)(k+2)\left(\frac{k}{3}+1\right)=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}$$

Comment: oh okay i forgot you can also use those to substitute

Comment: That's what you always have to do. Find a way to use your case $n=k$ into the case $n=k+1$.